# Create multiple columns in a dataframe based on the same condition

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am trying to create multiple columns in a dataframe based on one if statement condition at a time.  I created a define function like the one below to return 2 values for each if statement with the second if statement nested within the first one , and then apply the function to the dataframe to create 4 new columns. Obviously, this is incorrect and hope to get some help or other options to achieve the same result. Thanks!

```
def group(df):
  if df['a'] == 'one':
    low1 = 10
    high1 = 60

    if df['b'] == 'two':
    low2 = 20
    high2 = 70

    return low1, high1, low2, high2

df['low1', 'high1', 'low2', 'high2'] = df.apply(group, axis=1)
```

And results in a dataframe like this one...

```
 a   b    low1   high1   low2  high2
one        10     60     
one  two   10     60       20    70
```

Comment: I don't understand your code completely. But it is possible. In here second if condition never reaches. you need to swap those if conditions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Lucefer, if the first condition is true, it will never reach the second condition. So, swapping the if statements might work for you.

```
def group(df):
     if df['a'] == 'one' & df['b'] == 'two':
        low2 = 20
        high2 = 70
        return low2, high2

    if df['a'] == 'one':
        low1 = 10
        high1 = 60
        return low1, high1
```